# Is "the Eggshell Rule" applicable in England?

Tags: united-kingdom

I understand that, in the USA, the [Eggshell Rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv5lqcG7omM) stipulates that defendants must take victims as they find them.

Is the same true in England?

Comment: Could I recommend a quote or even just a link to the relevant page on (Wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggshell_skull#Law]. I know it's not a good source for answers (especially that page given the notes on it), but it might help people who can't watch YouTube videos for whatever reason to understand the concept under discussion.

Comment: Note that this description seems to invert the Eggshell rule, where it is that *plaintiffs* must "take" defendants as they find them.

Comment: @sharur, pardon? The description seems quite on-point. If a person takes an unlawful action that isn't _calculated_ to do severe harm but does so anyhow, that person becomes a defendant; and the person to whom they did harm becomes a plaintiff (or the state on their behalf). The defendent (who did harm) is liable for the damage they caused to the plaintiff, regardless of whether the intended magnitude of that harm was lesser than its actual magnitude.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Perhaps it is merely me who is confused.

Comment: @sharur This guy explains it well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iv5lqcG7omM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

The principle caselaw is *R v Hayward (1908) 21 Cox 692*

> A husband and wife had an argument that led to the husband chasing his wife out into the street.  The wife collapsed during this altercation and died.  Whist the husband did not physically touch her, he did shout threats at her.  The wife was found to have been suffering from an abnormality of the thyroid gland that neither was aware of that meant that fright or shock could cause death if combined with physical exertion.  The husband was charged with manslaughter.
>
> [...]
>
> The husband was found guilty of manslaughter.  No actual proof of violence was necessary as long as the defendant’s unlawful act, which was the threat of violence, caused her fright leading to her death.  **The criminal law acknowledges that an assailant must take their victim as they find them...** [Source](https://www.lawteacher.net/cases/r-v-hayward.php)

And...

> The defendant chased his wife out of the house shouting threats at her. She collapsed and died. He did not physically touch her. She was suffering from a rare thyroid condition which could lead to death where physical exertion was accompanied by fright and panic. Both the defendant and his wife were unaware she had this condition.
>
> Held:
>
> The defendant was liable for constructive manslaughter as his unlawful act (assault) caused death. The egg shell (thin) skull rule applied. He was therefore fully liable despite the fact an ordinary person of reasonable fortitude would not have died in such circumstances... [Source](http://www.e-lawresources.co.uk/R-v-Hayward.php)

Comment: Note that this seems to be the opposite of what the question is asking; either the original asking misunderstood, or had a transcription error, since they ask if the "*defendant* must take the *plaintiff* as they find them", and not vice versa.

Comment: @sharur I don't follow you. .? I read "*defendants must take plaintiffs as they find them*" as equating to "*assailant must take their victim as they find them*"

Comment: The case of [Smith v Leech Brain & Co (1962) 2 QB 405](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_v_Leech_Brain_%26_Co_Ltd) described by Wikipedia as a "landmark case" shows the rule remained in force. in 1962

Comment: Personally, in the UK a relative got injured through a small amount of negligence, and many people would have just walked away from it. She didn’t, she suffered actually quite badly. I found a newspaper article by pure coincidence, gave it to her, she gave it to a lawyer, and received a considerable amount of money in a settlement. Which was in line with her injury, even though totally out of line with the guilt of the party causing it (some employee hadn’t put a ladder away safely).

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to cite authoritative English law textbooks, rather than Wikipedia or unsubstantiated websites.

> Another area in which evaluative judgements of this sort are made concerns the question
> of remoteness: should a defendant be liable for a greater extent of damage than he
> could reasonably have foreseen would occur as a result of his negligence? The courts have
> held that the *extent of damage* need not have been foreseeable as long as there was foreseeability
> of the *kind of damage* sustained by the claimant. An illustration is the so-called ‘eggshell
> skull’ principle, which grants recovery in full to a claimant who is unusually vulnerable
> or susceptible to the consequences of a particular kind of injury. An employee who sustains
> a life-threatening disease when an accident at work triggers a condition that would otherwise
> have lain dormant will recover damages in full for the consequences of the illness, even
> though the accident itself was comparatively minor and its consequences could not have
> been predicted.<sup>47</sup> This outcome can be seen as striking a compromise between the idea that
> the extent of the defendant’s legal liability should be strictly limited to his degree of personal
> responsibility and the idea that he should be made fully liable for the consequences,
> in terms of the increased risk of harm to others, of his behaviour. It is significant that the
> courts yet again treat this issue of remoteness differently according to whether injury to the
> person or interference with economic interests is at stake, with the latter being accorded
> less extensive protection.<sup>48</sup>
>
> 47 *Smith v. Leech, Brain & Co. Ltd* [1962] 2 QB 405.
> 48 See below, ch. 5, sec. 3(E)–(F).

*Markesinis and Deakin's Tort Law* (2019, 8 edition, OUP), p. 92.

> #### (D) Extent of the damage
>
> **Personal injury** Before *The Wagon Mound* was decided, it was well established that,
> in relation to personal injury, the defendant had to ‘take the claimant as he found him’.
> This meant that the victim could claim damages for the entire injury to his person, even though, owing to some special bodily sensitivity, it was greater than would have been
> suffered by the ordinary individual. Thus, a haemophiliac,144 or an extreme neurotic,145
> who sustains greater injury than the ordinary person, can recover the full extent of their
> damage, even though the defendant could not have foreseen such extensive injury. The
> courts have held that *The Wagon Mound* has not affected this principle, commonly
> termed the ‘egg-shell skull’ rule. *Smith v Leech Brain & Co Ltd*146 is illustrative:
>
> > A negligently inflicted burn on C’s lip resulted in him dying of cancer. The tissues in his lip
> > in which the cancer developed were in a premalignant condition at the time when the burn
> > occurred. Ds were held liable for the damage resulting from the death.
>
> In a similar way, in *Robinson v Post Office*,147 the defendants carelessly lacerated
> the claimant’s leg. A doctor’s subsequent anti-tetanus injection caused encephalitis
> because the claimant was allergic to the injected serum. The defendants were held
> liable.148

> 144 *Bidwell v Briant* (1956) Times, 9 May.
> 145 *Love v Port of London Authority* [1959] 2 Lloyd’s Rep 541; *Malcolm v Broadhurst* [1970] 3 All ER 508;
> *Brice v Brown* [1984] 1 All ER 997.
> 146 [1962] 2 QB 405. 147 [1974] 2 All ER 737.
> 148 See also *Environment Agency v Ellis* [2009] PIQR P5 (C had a degenerative spinal condition prior to the accident for which D was responsible: according to May LJ, at [36], this was akin to an egg-shell skull).

Christian Witting, *Street on Torts* (2021, 16 edn, OUP), p. 190-1.